# iOS Navigation Bar Icon Size iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, uinavigationbar

Excuse me if this has been asked but I cannot seem to find a good answer.

I have vector PNG icons that were generated at 64x64 pixels.

What I'm trying figure out is how to add them as custom nav bar button icons so they look good in iOS8/iPhone 6 down to iPhone4s.

It seems like when I add the 64x64 icon in XCode and associate the icon with the custom button it doesn't scale down, it just remains 64x64 which is too big for the nav bar itself.

What is the best way to handle this? I don't want want it to look pixelated in in retina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add to project 2 files for each devices scales with such names:

- your_icon_name@2x.png - for iPhone4, 4s, 5, 5s and iPhone6;
- your_icon_name@3x.png - for iPhone6 plus.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html - The sizes of icons for each scale.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17 - This to learn deeper about different resolutions support in iOS.